# JQuery getjson ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is a javascript file which is supposed to load a php file named json.php 
Whenever I try to run the code on mozilla or chrome I always check the console both the js and php files are executed but nothing happens. Obviously I have created the html file that relies on this.

```js
$(function(){
              $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#carica").click(function(){  
                    $.getJSON("json.php", {residenza:$("#residenza").val()}, function(data){
                        $.each(data, function(i, data){                        
                            var dati = "<p>Nome italiano: " +data.NomeIta 
                                + ", Nome inglese: " + data.NomeIng + 
                                ", residenza: " +data.residenza + "</p>" 
                            $(dati).appendTo("#intro");
                        });
                    })
                })
                
            })
  }) 



<?php

$dbhost = 'dbhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbname = 'disney';
$dbpass = 'passw';
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$cmd = 'SELECT * FROM personaggi where residenza = :residenza';
$residenza = $_GET['residenza'];

$result = $conn->prepare($cmd);
$result->bindValue("residenza", $residenza);
$result->execute();
$return_arr = array();
$row_array = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['NomeIng'] = $row['NomeInglese'];
    $row_array['NomeIta'] = $row['NomeItaliano'];
    $row_array['residenza'] = $row['residenza'];

    array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
}
$conn = NULL;
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it-IT" dir="ltr" xlm:lang="it-IT" xlmns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
          <title>json</title>
          <meta name="description" content="json dom in jquery">
          <meta name="keywords" content="json, php, web, design, jquery">
          <meta name="author" content="Riccardo Cirodano">
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ajax/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../ajax/json.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <input type="text" id="residenza"></input>
   <button id="carica">Carica</button>
   <br><br>
   <div id="intro"></div> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `json.php` returning?

Comment: don't worry I have been able to solve the question on my own...I will immediately sign this post as solved